# What is the 95% confidence interval of a function with multiple coefficients?

Tags: confidence-interval, regression-coefficients

I have a function made up of several regression coefficients, for example, let's say it's:

$$y(x) = \beta_1x + \beta_2x^2$$

assuming we have the covariance matrix for $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$, how can I (if at all) obtain a confidence interval of the function $y(x)$? So for each $x$, what is the 95% CI at that point given the error around the beta coefficients?

Comment: Do you really mean "each $x$" or did you intend to write "for each $(x,x_2)$"?  The latter makes sense but the former does not unless you suppose $(x,x_2)$ are a bivariate random variable, in which case you would need to supply some information about their joint distribution.

Comment: hi @whuber sorry this meant to read x^2 not x_2, so it's the same x. To give context, in my specific case it's a relative risk function that has several beta coefficients for various functions of x where x is the intake of a substance, and y(x) the relative risk of mortality associated to the substance intake.